# Comb space is contractible proof

Tags: algebraic-topology

For each positive integer $n$, let $I_n=\{1/n\}\times I$ as a subset of $I\times I$. Let $X=(I\times 0)\cup (0\times I)\cup (\cup_{n≥1}I_n)$. I do not understand how is this space contractible. Though I saw a proof involving inclusion map from line segment joining b$(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ to $X$, I did not understand it.

Answer (score 4):

Let $h:[0,1]\times X\rightarrow X$ be defined by $h(t,x,y)=(x,(1-t)y)$. This map is continuous because it is the restriction of the continuous map $I\times I^2\rightarrow I^2$. This contracts $X$ to the line $I\times\{0\}$. But this space is also contractible, as it is homeomorphic to $I$. It follows that $X$ is contractible.